# In Robinson Crusoe, Can I do single-pawn actions multiple times on the same card?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

For example, can every character use one of their pawns to do 3 'gathering' actions in a round? All three actions would require dice rolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official rulebook](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Robinson.pdf): (p.6)

> **Note!**
>
> **Each Action** **can be taken multiple times in the same round**,
> except for the Threat Action, which is always a one time Action taken
> on a specific card, after which the card is discarded.

Only restrictions regarding "Gathering resources" are (p.9)

> This [Gathering] Action **cannot be taken** directly on the Island **tile with the
> players’ Camp** since players get resources from that tile during the
> Production phase.

and

> You can **gather** **only once per round from each source**; i.e. if one
> player assigns his pawn(s) to gather from one source, no other player
> can gather from that same source this round.

---

Addtionally, from the [FAQ 1.0](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/84727/faq-robinson) (made by Ignacy Trzewiczek himself) (p.10)

> **If I put one of my pawns on any Action, will the second pawn placed
> there automatically support me? Or could we, for example, place 3
> single pawns on the Weapons track, to build 3 Weapons (and roll the
> dice three times)?**
>
> It's your choice if you want to treat each pawn
> separately.